# Does HealthKit step count show on xcode simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, healthkit

I am building an app and retrieving a users step count from HealthKit

There is no error, and I was curious to see if when you run code on xcode using the simulator the step count will always be 0 by default as locations are defaulted?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I think no.. Apple Healthkit uses iPhone's hardware and some specific services to count the steps. In Simulator it's not possible.

Answer (score 35):

That's actually possible. Follow the below step

1. Go to simulator home and open 'Health' App. after that
2. Tap on Health Data from the bottom menu.
3. Tap on Activity Box
4. Scroll down and find steps and tap on it.
5. To add custom steps tap on '+' icon on the top right corner.

You can now add dummy steps data for Apple Health Kit. Cheers!

Comment: great little tip for getting this working on a simulator